# How save image in parse cloud using javascript

Tags: javascript, image, parse-platform, base64, parse-cloud-code

we are trying to save image in Parse using CloudCode.
we followed this [link](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/new-cloud-modules-for-images-and-users/).
we are new to javascript,plz guide us...!
Thanks in advance.......

```
var url = file.url();
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url: url }).then(function(response) {
  // Create an Image from the data.
  var image = new Image();
  return image.setData(response.buffer);

}.then(function(image) {
  // Scale the image to a certain size.
  return image.scale({ width: 64, height: 64 });

}.then(function(image) {
  // Get the bytes of the new image.
  return image.data();

}.then(function(buffer) {
  // Save the bytes to a new file.
  var file = new Parse.File("image.jpg", { base64: data.toString("base64"); });
  return file.save();
}); 
we getting error like this
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a repeated syntax mistake at the end of each function parameter to then.

The syntax is:

```
somePromise.then(function() {
    // success
}).then(function() {  // your code says '}.' instead of '}).'
    // success
});
```

There's an optional error function callback as second param:

```
somePromise.then(function() {
    // success
}).then(function() {
    // success
}, function(error) {
    // error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the close parentheses for each promise callback. Your code should be this :

```
var url = file.url();
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url: url }).then(function(response) {
  // Create an Image from the data.
  var image = new Image();
  return image.setData(response.buffer);

}).then(function(image) {
  // Scale the image to a certain size.
  return image.scale({ width: 64, height: 64 });

}).then(function(image) {
  // Get the bytes of the new image.
  return image.data();

}).then(function(buffer) {
  // Save the bytes to a new file.
  var file = new Parse.File("image.jpg", { base64: data.toString("base64"); });
  return file.save();
});
```